# How to handle filenames with dollar character ($) in bash?

Tags: bash

I have managed to cobble together the following script that moves files from one Samba share to another. It seems to work for all legal windows filenames except when there is a dollar character ($) in the filename. Typical filename it fails on is: ~$file.doc

Any help would be appreciated.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to move old files from public to quarantine

 srcbase=/net/public
 destbase=/net/quarantine
 logfile=$srcbase/moved.log
 date > $logfile 2>1&
 find $srcbase -noleaf -atime +30 -print0 | while IFS="" read -r -d "" file ; do
   if [ -f "$file" ]; then
     relname="${file#*$srcbase}"
     destname="$destbase$relname"
     destdir="$(dirname "$destname")"
     if [ ! -d "$destdir" ]; then
       cmd1="mkdir -p \""$destdir"\""
       eval "$cmd1"  >> $logfile 2>&1
     fi
     cmd="mv --backup=t -v \""$file"\" \""$destname"\""
     eval "$cmd" >> $logfile 2>&1
     if [ -e "$destname" ]; then
       cmd2="touch -a \""$destname"\""
       eval "$cmd2" >> $logfile 2>&1
     fi
   fi
 done
 date >> $logfile 2>1&
 echo Deleting empty directories from "$srcbase" >> $logfile 2>&1
 find "$srcbase" -type d -empty -delete >> $logfile 2>&1
```

Comment: Are you sure the files with $ in are not locked? It's common to have temporary files with a $ in the name, and they are usually unreadable due to being already open by another process.

Comment: Why are you putting your commands in variables? Just do `mv --backup=t -v "$file" "$destname" >> $logfile 2>&1` directly, for example. This also saves you from having to do all that awkward extra quoting and escaping.

Answer (score 4):

Of course you are. You're using `eval`.

BASH FAQ [entry #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: +1 [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is about avoiding putting commands in variables (applicable to the OP's code) and [BashFAQ/048](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) is about the security issues of `eval` (also applicable).

Answer (score 3):

The problem probably comes from using the filenames in a variable that is evaled.

If you would use single quotes in the setup of the eval it prevents that the $ is interpreted there e.g.:

```
cmd2="touch -a '$destname'"
```

The `$destname` is still replaced when cmd is created.

**BUT:** I'll advise strongly against building evals from filenames you find on a filesystem.  This is a huge backdoor.  e.g.: what if some prankster creates a file name `; rm -rf /` on the source filesystem?

[Explanation of the security issues with eval](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)

Comment: +1, `eval` is a dangerous tool that needs to be handled with care.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is your use of `eval`. I recommend against it since it's very, very rarely necessary and extremely difficult to use. I don't see any need for it in your case

If you replace the contents of your loop with this

```
   if [ -f "$file" ]; then
     relname="${file#*$srcbase}"
     destname="$destbase$relname"
     destdir="$(dirname "$destname")"
     if [ ! -d "$destdir" ]; then
        mkdir -p "$destdir" >> $logfile 2>&1
     fi
     mv --backup=t -v "$file" "$destname"
     if [ -e "$destname" ]; then
        touch -a "$destname" >> $logfile 2>&1
     fi
   fi
```

It should work just as well, even with $ in the file name.

Did you find that this was not the case?